# Accessing Nested Interface Data Variable

Tags: java, interface, nested

I can't access the variable `i` for this code:

```
interface three{
    void how();
    interface two{
        int i=2;
        void what();
    }
}

class one implements three,two{

    public void how(){
        System.out.println("\nHow! i = " + i);
        what();
    }

    public void what(){
        System.out.println("\nWhat! i = " + i);
    }

    public static void main(String args[]){
        one a = new one();
        a.how();
        a.what();

    }
}
```

The generated error is:

```
one.java:17: error: cannot find symbol
System.out.println("\nWhat! i = " + i);                                          
symbol:   variable i
location: class one
```

Comment: You can always access it as `two.i`. Anyway, your approach seemed to compile for me in IntelliJ. Also, nesting interface like this might be complicated and cause troubles.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can code this as below

I've separate the classes for your reference

**three.java**

```
 public interface three{
   void how();
 }
```

then compile it as ***javac three.java***

after that

**two.java**

```
 public interface two{
        int i=2;
        void what();
 }
```

compile it as ***javac two.java***

then

**one.java**

```
class one implements two,three{
   public void how(){
      System.out.println("\nHow! i = " + i);
     what();
   }

   public void what(){
      System.out.println("\nWhat! i = " + i);
   }

   public static void main(String args[]){
     one a = new one();
     a.how();
     a.what();
   }
}
```

then compile as below

***javac one.java***

after that run it as

***java one***

then you will get the following output

```
 How! i = 2

 What! i = 2

 What! i = 2
```

In your problem what I understand is interface three methods are unable to access the interface two's ***i*** variable,

**Or you can code like this**

***three.java***

```
 public interface three{
   void how();
    interface two{
        int i=2;
        void what();
    }
 }
```

***one.java***

```
class one implements three.two{
   public void how(){
       System.out.println("\nHow! i = " + i);
       what();
   }

   public void what(){
       System.out.println("\nWhat! i = " + i);
   }

   public static void main(String args[]){
       three.two a = new one();
       a.what();
       one b = new one();//created this to call the how() method in one.java  
       b.how();
    }
}
```

the output as below

```
 What! i = 2

 How! i = 2

 What! i = 2
```

Hope this will help to resolve your problem.

Answer (score 1):

You should create interface outside so that other class can access it.

```
interface three {
    void how();
}

interface two {
    int i = 2;

    void what();
}

public class one implements three, two {

    public void how() {
        System.out.println("\nHow! i = " + i);
        what();
    }

    public void what() {
        System.out.println("\nWhat! i = " + i);
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        one a = new one();
        a.how();
        a.what();

    }
}
```